# How do I make the gmailapp send function more readable using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, format, gmail, google-forms

```
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '.<b> ' + question + '</b>:\n ' + answer  + '\n';
   if(answer === 'English'){var send=1;}
   if(answer === 'Japanese'){var send=2;}

  var address1 = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var title1 = '【incoming】Notification';
  var title2 = '【incoming】Notification';

  var content = '確認してください。The form was submitted with the following contents.\n\n' + question + message;

  const html = `
  content1
  content2
  content3`;
  const options = {
    'htmlBody': html.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
  }

  var option = {};
  option.from = "myemail@gmail.com";
  

  if(send === 1){var to1 = [address1];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to1,  title1,  content, option);}
```

Update: This code works except the bold parts.
[image]

How would I set up the bold parts? it seems just the html is popping up instead of actually being bold.

Comment: Are you looking to formatting your email with HTML? The fourth argument for [`GmailApp.sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) allows you to include HTML body

Comment: Yeah, anything from like just bold to linebreaks or anything like that. 

GmailApp.sendEmail("allmanagers@company.com",<b>title</b>,<br>content);  <  would something like that work?

Answer (score 1):

Off course you could add `<br>` directly.

But it may be more readable to simply break with lines and replace it at once afterwards.

```js
  const html = `<b>title</b>
  content1
  content2
  content3`;
  const options = {
    'htmlBody': html.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail("allmanagers@company.com",title,content,options);
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more on where that's placed? I tried to copy and paste the same way you've set it up there but that didn't result in any breaks or any bolds

Comment: Have you added `options` to `sendEmail`?

Comment: Added, it works great with the bold. I updated the top post. The bold didn't work though.

Comment: Your HTML body is in `options` while you pass `option` to the `sendEmail` method

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Should I move it to sendEmail?

Comment: `GmailApp.sendEmail("allmanagers@company.com",title,content,options);` <- the last argument needs to be added

Comment: That hasn't quite formatted with bold. I'm not sure that solved the bold issue

Comment: You have typo, not `option` but `options`

Comment: That fixed the bold but now the content doesn't come through. it literally says "content"

Comment: Because it it a string 'content' not a variable. You should modify it yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236220/discussion-between-ari-and-idfurw).