# Google sheets script to send emails based on color of cell and name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets that look like this:

[image: Main Sheet]
[image: Contact Sheet]

I'm trying to write a script that does the following:

- Look in the date column for a value that matches today's date
- If a match is found, look under the different names in that row for a blank cell with a white color background (#ffffff)
- If a match is found, send an email to the manager of that particular name (e.g., in B2, Jack has a white cell, so send an email to Jack's manager (rob@something.com; pulled up from the 'Contact' sheet)

Currently I have the following code:

```
function sendEmail3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  const data = sheet.getRange(2,1,27,7).getValues();

// console.log(data);

 data.forEach(row => {
const sysDate = new Date();
  sysDate.setHours(0);
  sysDate.setMinutes(0);
  sysDate.setSeconds(0); 

const sheetDate = new Date(row[0])

// format both system date and sheet date so that they are identical strings
const sysDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(sysDate, "GMT-0700", "MM/dd/yyyy");
const sheetDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, "GMT-0700", "MM/dd/yyyy");

// a simple if statement with a console log. This needs to be replaced
// if the dates match, then look in that row for blank cells with white backgrounds (#ffffff)
 if (sysDateFormatted == sheetDateFormatted) {
  console.log("They are equal");
} else {
  console.log("they are not equal");
}

// I tried the following and was able to get the backgrounds for each cell in this range
const specificData = sheet.getRange(2,2,999,6) // this range doesn't include the headers
const dataColor = specificData.getBackgrounds();
console.log(dataColor);

})
}
```

I can't seem to put all the pieces together. If anyone could help me sort out the logic for this one I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- do not include the variables in loop that is not changing
- dates got by `getValue`/`getValues` are already `date` object
- `formatDate` with `MM/dd/yyyy` is not referring to the time so no need to `setHours`/`setMinutes`/`setSeconds`

```js
function sendEmail3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const data = range.getValues();
  const dataColor = range.getBackgrounds();

  const contact = ss.getSheetByName('Contact').getDataRange().getValues();
  const manager = {};
  for (const row of contact) {
    manager[row[0]] = {
      name: row[1],
      email: row[2]
    };
  }

  const sysDate = new Date();
  const sysDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(sysDate, "GMT-0700", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const sheetDate = data[i][0];
    const sheetDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, "GMT-0700", "MM/dd/yyyy");

    if (sysDateFormatted === sheetDateFormatted) {
      for (let j = 1; j < data[0].length; j++) {
        if (dataColor[i][j] === '#ffffff') {
          const name = data[0][j];
          sendMail(name);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  function sendMail(name) {
    const subject = '...';
    const body = `...${name}...`;
    GmailApp.sendEmail(manager[name].email, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. How do I add the manager's name in the body of the email? For example: const body = `Hi ${managerName}, <br><br>` Also, the html tags aren't working inside the text here (<br>)

Comment: `manager[name].name` would give the manger's name. Html tags only work in html mail which you could pass the html content with `htmlBody` options. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68841515/16125139).

Comment: Thank you! what is the manager[name] called is that an array? why the use of square brackets here [ ] ?

Comment: `manager` is a dictionary object previously defined. `manager[name]` is a referring to the property of value stored in variable `name`, ie `Jack`, and value is an object with properties `name` and `email`. Try to log each of them to have better understanding.